# Whats the best way to save images? As actual image or base64?

Tags: image, base64

What is the best way to save images. Any pros and cons with both ways? Does any of them load guicker or is it simular? How does for example Instagram save their images? 
I mean as an .jpg/.png or as a base64 string in my mySql database and use that in an img tag.

And also, what is the best way to upload it? 
If as an .jpg/.png - To use formData and send a base64 string that I convert and create the image with on the server or to use a image upload plugin that uploads the image?

Is using formData making the images larger in file size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If by "actual image" you mean a .png or .jpg file or similar, then saving the images is probably better. If you encode as Base64 you require any applications that are going to use the image to go through an extra conversion and then load it as a .jpg, .png, or whatever.

The only reason to use Base64 is if you need to transmit the data in a form that only accepts ASCII characters, such as by email. But for storing locally on the user's machine, you would never want to use Base64.

Comment: Additionally, the base64 representation will take 1/3 more disk space.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes as an .jpg or .png file, and sorry but I meant saving the base64 string in my database and use it in an img tag. The images is saved on my server or as a base64 string in my mySql database. So is it quicker to load a list with lets say 100 images as a base 64 or as a .jpg/.png?